# Adsense Banner complains about space when handling screen rotate

Tags: android, orientation, adsense, banner

I use

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

im my AndroidManifest.xml to avoid restart of my Activity on Screen Orientation change.
It works fine, but I noticed that my Adsense Banner complains about to tittle space after turning to horizontal and then vertical again.

> W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 312x50 dp.

How to fix this? I do not use *onConfigurationChanged* method in my Mainactivity

Comment: Every ad requires a minimum size to be displayed (see the AdMob console). Cause onConfigurationChanged often changes the view sizes. You have To make sure you have enough space available and reload the ad.

Comment: I tried this but no change:

 `@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        {
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }`